# android Failed to find provider info

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

Theses 2 errors keep showing up. I searched a lot for solutions but I couldn't fix them.

E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?

E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.playpersia.bicyclemap.LocationssProviderslocation

**My Provider**

```
public class LocationssProviders extends ContentProvider {

String TAG="LocationssProviders";

public static String AUTHORITY="com.playpersia.bicyclemap.LocationssProviders";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =Uri.parse("content://" +AUTHORITY + "locations");

// MIME types used for searching words or looking up a single location

public static final String LOCATION_MIME_TYPE= ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE +
        "/com.playpersia.bicyclemap";

public static final String DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE =ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE +
        "/com.playpersia.bicyclemap";

private LocationDatabase mLocation;

//UriMatcher

private static final  int SEARCH_NAMES=0;
private static final  int GET_NAMES=1;
private static final  int SEARCH_SUGGEST=2;
private static final  int REFRESH_SHORTCUT=3;
private static final UriMatcher sURIMATCHER= buildUriMatcher();


private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher(){
    UriMatcher matcher= new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , "locations", SEARCH_NAMES);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "locations/#", GET_NAMES);

    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY,SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY +
            "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);



    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY,SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT,REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT
            +"/*", REFRESH_SHORTCUT);

    return matcher;

}
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {

    mLocation= new LocationDatabase(getContext());

    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    switch (sURIMATCHER.match(uri))
    {
        case  SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            if (selectionArgs == null){

                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "selectionArgs nust be provided for the Uri:" + uri);
            }

            return getSuggestion(selectionArgs[0]);

        case SEARCH_NAMES:

            if (selectionArgs == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
            }

            return  search(selectionArgs[0]);
        case GET_NAMES:
            return  getName(uri);
        case  REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return  refreshShortcut(uri);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);

    }

}



private Cursor getSuggestion(String query) {

    query=query.toLowerCase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            BaseColumns._ID,
            LocationDatabase.KET_NAME,
            LocationDatabase.KEY_LOCATION,

            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID

    };

    return mLocation.getNameMatches(query, columns);
}

private  Cursor search (String query){
    query=query.toLowerCase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            BaseColumns._ID,
            LocationDatabase.KET_NAME,
            LocationDatabase.KEY_LOCATION,
    };

    return mLocation.getNameMatches(query, columns);

}

private Cursor getName(Uri uri){

    String rowId= uri.getLastPathSegment();
    String[] columns= new String[]{
            LocationDatabase.KET_NAME,
            LocationDatabase.KEY_LOCATION,

    };
    return mLocation.getName(rowId, columns);
}

private Cursor refreshShortcut(Uri uri) {
    String rowId= uri.getLastPathSegment();
    String [] columns= new String[]{

            BaseColumns._ID,
            LocationDatabase.KET_NAME,
            LocationDatabase.KEY_LOCATION,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID

    };

    return mLocation.getName(rowId, columns);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (sURIMATCHER.match(uri)){
        case  SEARCH_NAMES:
            return LOCATION_MIME_TYPE;
        case GET_NAMES:
            return DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE;
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return SearchManager.SHORTCUT_MIME_TYPE;
        default:
            throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Unkniwn URL" +
                    uri);
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();

}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();

   }
    }
```

**Manifrst**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.playpersia.bicyclemap">

    <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="24"
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.playpersia.bicyclemap.permission.MAP_RECEIVES"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <permission
        android:name="com.google.maps.android.utils.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.maps.android.utils.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:debuggable="true"

        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBS8V9TGhcFUIpt0AIUORXr7-H4XZDQeXw" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH">

                </action>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"
                />

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".IntroWelcomePager.WelcomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CheckNetConnActivity" />


        <!-- Provides search suggestions for words and their definitions. -->

        <provider android:name="com.playpersia.bicyclemap.LocationssProviders"
            android:authorities="com.playpersia.bicyclemap.LocationssProviders"
            android:exported="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:multiprocess="true"
            android:label="@string/provider_locations"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You forgot about "/"

Comment: thanks, I fixed it. But it still gives me the error @Selvin

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =Uri.parse("content://" +AUTHORITY);
```

instead of

```
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =Uri.parse("content://" +AUTHORITY + "locations");
```

You don't need to mention your "locations" contract in content uri.

Hope this helps.